# How to use ComplexQueryFilter

Tags: workload-scheduler, tivoli-work-scheduler

I try to use ComplexQueryFilter in TWSz Java API application. I want to display all applications except one for example SORT#APP. I do something like that:

```
QueryFilter qf = new QueryFilter();
ComplexQueryFilter cqf = new ComplexQueryFilter();
compleqFilter.setOperator(ComplexQueryFilter.NOT);
compleqFilter.setFilter(JobStreamFilters.JOB_STREAM_NAME, "SORT#APP");
queryFilter.setComplexFilter(cqf);
QueryResult queryResult = model.queryTWSObject(JobStream.class, qf, 25, null);
```

But it doesn't work.I still gets full list of applications. How to use ComplexQueryFilter properly?

Answer (score 0):

ComplexQueryFilter are supported only for TWSd, they are not available for TWSz